# Customize form to make it multipaged

Tags: forms, drupal-7, multipage, hook-form-alter

A module I am using provides a single paged configuration form. But for my additional configuration purposes, I am attempting to make it multipaged with one additional page for collecting extra configuration data.

I am implementing **hook_form_alter** and I included the following code:

```
$form['next'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('next'),
        '#page callback' => array('custom_ucreate_profile2'),
        '#button_type' => 'button',
    );
```

I have also created the **custom_ucreate_profile2** menu link. The configuration page at the end of that link works fine. But the problem is when I click on the "next" button, the current page just reloads and do not navigate to custom_ucreate_profile2.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rolling your own solution, which can be hard to maintain as time goes on, you could try the [field_group module](http://drupal.org/project/field_group).  There's even a [video showing how to use the multipage features](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhA5b5KpHZw).